# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond - It worked but no longer working

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-views

I keep receiving this error message while trying to create a signup endpoint where users can verify their email.

I have registered and sent various verification mails and received it but now it's showing this issue when I did not make any change to it

I had this problem previously when my windscribe VPN was on however I've turned it off and also made sure that my internet connection is working yet I still have the same problem

TRACEBACK

```
Internal Server Error: /users/register/recruiter/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\users\views.py", line 184, in post
    RecruiterUtil.send_email(data)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\users\utils.py", line 21, in send_email
    email.send()
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 298, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 127, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\CS50\afritechjobsite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 85, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 851, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 836, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
[26/Jul/2023 08:12:39] "POST /users/register/recruiter/ HTTP/1.1" 500 20320
```

VIEWS

```
class RecruiterRegisterView(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = RecruiterRegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user=request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        user_data = serializer.data
        # Get the email of the current user
        user = Recruiter.objects.get(email = user_data['email'])
        # Get access to create a token for the current user
        token = RefreshToken.for_user(user).access_token
        # using the imported modeule, we need to get the current site
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        # using the imported reverse module, we reverse with the url name
        relativeLink = reverse('users:verify_recruiter_email')
        # returns the concatenated domain
        absoluteurl = 'http://'+ current_site + relativeLink + "?token=" + str(token)
        email_body = 'Hi, ' + user.username + 'Use link below to verify your email \n' + absoluteurl
        data={'email_body': email_body, 'email_subject': 'Verify your email', 'to_email': user.email,}
        RecruiterUtil.send_email(data)

        return Response(data=user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

SERIALIZER

```
class RecruiterRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=68, min_length=6, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recruiter
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'password')

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if not attrs['username'].isalnum():
            raise serializers.ValidationError('The username should only contain alphanumeric characters')
        return attrs
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Recruiter.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

UTIL

```
class RecruiterUtil:
    @staticmethod
    def send_email(data):
        try:
            email = EmailMessage(subject=data['email_subject'], body=data['email_body'], to=[data['to_email']])
            email.send()
        except SMTPException as e:
            print("Email sending failed:", e)
```

SETTING

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'cbp'
```

URL

```
path("register/recruiter/", RecruiterRegisterView.as_view(), name="recruiter_register"),
```

The password is generated using the gmail custom app password.

When I try to register it returns that error still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace, the email-sending process took too long to fulfil leading to the error encountered. This is typical of email services and many other external services that you don't have control over.

To avoid this kind of issue, it's almost always recommended to use [`celery`](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) or any other task queue to handle tasks like this.

For instance, you can have a [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html)  task in `name_of_app/tasks.py` that looks like this:

```py
from typing import Any
from uuid import UUID

from celery import shared_task
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags


@shared_task
def send_email_message(
    subject: str, template_name: str, user_id: UUID, ctx: dict[str, Any]
) -> None:
    """Send email to users."""
    html_message = render_to_string(template_name, ctx)
    plain_message = strip_tags(html_message)
    send_mail(
        subject=subject,
        message=plain_message,
        from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        recipient_list=[...],
        fail_silently=False,
        html_message=html_message,
    )
```

The task can then be called when you want to send the email:

```py
...
send_email_message.delay(subject=..., template_name=..., user_id=..., ctx=...)
...
```

With this, the email-sending process is delegated to a background task and that will allow your process to be smooth, fast, scalable and efficient.

It should be noted that `template_name` should be equal to a verified HTML file with your email message. You can check this [post](https://dev.to/sirneij/authentication-system-using-python-django-and-sveltekit-user-registration-lb4) for more explanation.